# How can I flush a child process from nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I invoke an executable C program from nodejs using spawn, but the C program seems not be flushed every time. Then, my node program can only output the child process' stdout when the buffer is full(4K) or the child process exit.

To simply the scenario, the two parts code should be:

*invoke.js*

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var ps = spawn("./echo");
ps.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`); 
});
process.on("SIGINT", ps.kill);
```

*echo.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile int keep = 1;

void intHandler(int d){
    keep = 0;
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);
    int count = 0;
    while(keep) {
            printf("%d hello world!\r\n", ++count);
            sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**How could I get the output from echo in the invoke.js synchronus? One important thing is I cannot modify the echo.c, I only have binary**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the documentation about child processes/forks and how to pipe the child output to the parent process:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

> - 'pipe' - equivalent to ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] (the default)
> - 'ignore' - equivalent to ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore']
> - 'inherit' -equivalent to [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr] or [0,1,2]

In your case, if you don't need to do something more complex with the output, you can get rid of the `on.data` event listener and just initialize the spawned process with the inherit option. I've modified the SIGINT event binding to be more clear that the ps.kill is invoked.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var ps = spawn('./echo', { stdio: 'inherit' });

process.on('SIGINT', function (){
  console.log('sigint received');
  ps.kill();
});
```

Comment: that's great, and one more question is if i still use on.data, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @yuizhou I just found out that your code works as well. It is jus that there is a specific size that is buffered and after a certain point you will see the results being printed in the console. You can see this happening if you modify the echo.c file and you put in there more printfs with larger strings.

Comment: I run it on a linux environment. When the echo program's output is stdout, it auto flush when arriving \n, but once the io re-direct to other destination, its output will put into a buffer with 4K size. I can only see the output when the buffer is full or the process exit in the re-direct case. So I wonder can I modify the buffer's size or force flush the stream in my nodejs program since I cannot modify the echo program in the re-direct case.

Answer (score 0):

I found [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa) to be useful for this.

Comment: I think this lib is used for the sync process, but the C program I invoke contains a while-true loop to print something, it cannot stop until user's terminate. So this lib seems no idea for my case. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o

There are different between Windows and POSIX.
If child_process is spawned on Windows, only TTY type stdout work asynchronously.
`inherit` option make child_process asynchronously, because `process.stdout` is TTY type.